# Setting a different theme

Tags: android, themes

I want to use a few themes, for instance, Dark and Light.
I have written in the style.xml two different styles: DarkStyle and LightStyle. I have set part of the volatile properties by color.xml and part straight away.

```
<style name="BaseTheme.LightStyle">
<item name="clientBrand">@color/clientBrand</item>
<item name="desktopScreenBg">#E6E6E6</item>
</style>
<style name="BaseTheme.DarkStyle">
<item name="clientBrand">@color/clientBrand</item>
<item name="desktopScreenBg">#000000</item>
</style>
```

1. Which is the best practice to the choice theme
   a. Build time?
   b. Run time?
2. How I can to set to some other theme values from my theme.

`<style name="OtherTheme">
            <item name="android:textColor">dependsOnChosenTheme</item>
        </style>`

The final goal is:

```
<ViewGroup background = DarkOrLightColorBg/>
<TextView textColor = DarkOrLightColorBg/>
```

I figured out how to bind the desired theme in the build time

```
<style name="LightStyle">
<style name="DarkStyle">
//by requrements
<style name="DarkStyle.ActiveStyle">
```

Now, how I can do something like this?

```
<ViewGroup backgroun=ActiveStyle.colorBg/>
//Or
<style SomeTheme 
<item name="android:textColor">@style/ActiveStile.colorText</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an example](https://medium.com/@pkjvit/https-medium-com-pkjvit-android-multi-theme-night-mode-and-material-design-c186bf9fd678) how to create multi theme app. It is so easy, your activity has a context, inside context you could override method to inject selected theme by user.

Also if you don't need to runtime change, you could change theme at compile time, in AndroidManifest.xml.

[image]

Comment: this means i have to set all theme values to the components by the run time?

Comment: @Lavan Yeah, if you need to change theme in runtime. SharedPreferences could be like hash map persistence for saving selected theme.

Comment: No, I don't want. What i can't understand from your link is how and when i have to bind my theme resource to a component?

Comment: What i want is have the possibility to build .apk sometime with Dark Theme sometime with Light Theme

Comment: I got it. Did you think about AndroidManifest? This file is exactly for your case. There is an attribute android:theme inside application tag. I edited answer.

Comment: unfortunately this not good too, i try to find some solution where i don't need to bind a component to the theme by run time.